# Print Header and footer keeps repeating html

Tags: javascript, html, css, printing

I'm having a trouble title header and footer keeps repeating on every pages when prints I just want to display title at the top of the page and display the footer at the end of the print page. Can anyone help me ,suggest or provide solution you can see my fiddle  or html code below thank you!

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/reymark/49gz12wo/3/#&togetherjs=5fPPf6iaK2)

> entire html

```
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<style>
@media screen
{
.noPrint{}
.titles{display:none;}
.footer{display:none;}
}
@media print
{
.noPrint{display:none;}
.title{}
.footer{}
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<button onclick="printDiv();">Print it</button>
  <table class="report-container" name="table" id="table"  >
    <thead class="report-header">
  <th colspan="9"><div class="titles">Title Header <br></div></th>
   <tr>
     <td>ID Number</td>
     <td>Name</td>
     <td>Barangay</td>
     <td>Sex</td>
     <td>Sector</td>
     <td>Amount</td>
     <td>Signature/thumb</td>
     <td>ID &nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
     <td>Date Received</td>
   </tr>
   </thead>
  <tfoot>
   <tr>
    <td colspan=9><div class="footer">Title Footer</div></td>
   </tr>
</tfoot>
<tbody class="report-content">
  <tr>
     <td class="report-content-cell">
       <div class="main">fas</div>
     </td>
     <td>1</td>   
     <td>2</td> 
     <td>3</td>
     <td>4</td>
     <td>5</td>
     <td>6</td>
     <td>7</td>  
     <td>8</td> 
  </tr>
  <tr>
     <td class="report-content-cell">
       <div class="main">fas</div>
     </td>
     <td>1</td>   
     <td>2</td> 
     <td>3</td>
     <td>4</td>
     <td>5</td>
     <td>6</td>
     <td>7</td>  
     <td>8</td> 
  </tr>
  <tr>
     <td class="report-content-cell">
       <div class="main">fas</div>
     </td>
     <td>1</td>   
     <td>2</td> 
     <td>3</td>
     <td>4</td>
     <td>5</td>
     <td>6</td>
     <td>7</td>  
     <td>8</td> 
  </tr>
  <tr>
     <td class="report-content-cell">
       <div class="main">fas</div>
     </td>
     <td>1</td>   
     <td>2</td> 
     <td>3</td>
     <td>4</td>
     <td>5</td>
     <td>6</td>
     <td>7</td>  
     <td>8</td> 
  </tr>
  <tr>
     <td class="report-content-cell">
       <div class="main">fas</div>
     </td>
     <td>1</td>   
     <td>2</td> 
     <td>3</td>
     <td>4</td>
     <td>5</td>
     <td>6</td>
     <td>7</td>  
     <td>8</td> 
  </tr>
  <tr>
     <td class="report-content-cell">
       <div class="main">fas</div>
     </td>
     <td>1</td>   
     <td>2</td> 
     <td>3</td>
     <td>4</td>
     <td>5</td>
     <td>6</td>
     <td>7</td>  
     <td>8</td> 
  </tr>
  <tr>
     <td class="report-content-cell">
       <div class="main">fas</div>
     </td>
     <td>1</td>   
     <td>2</td> 
     <td>3</td>
     <td>4</td>
     <td>5</td>
     <td>6</td>
     <td>7</td>  
     <td>8</td> 
  </tr>
  <tr>
     <td class="report-content-cell">
       <div class="main">fas</div>
     </td>
     <td>1</td>   
     <td>2</td> 
     <td>3</td>
     <td>4</td>
     <td>5</td>
     <td>6</td>
     <td>7</td>  
     <td>8</td> 
  </tr>
  <tr>
     <td class="report-content-cell">
       <div class="main">fas</div>
     </td>
     <td>1</td>   
     <td>2</td> 
     <td>3</td>
     <td>4</td>
     <td>5</td>
     <td>6</td>
     <td>7</td>  
     <td>8</td> 
  </tr>
  <tr>
     <td class="report-content-cell">
       <div class="main">fas</div>
     </td>
     <td>1</td>   
     <td>2</td> 
     <td>3</td>
     <td>4</td>
     <td>5</td>
     <td>6</td>
     <td>7</td>  
     <td>8</td> 
  </tr>
  <tr>
     <td class="report-content-cell">
       <div class="main">fas</div>
     </td>
     <td>1</td>   
     <td>2</td> 
     <td>3</td>
     <td>4</td>
     <td>5</td>
     <td>6</td>
     <td>7</td>  
     <td>8</td> 
  </tr>
  <tr>
     <td class="report-content-cell">
       <div class="main">fas</div>
     </td>
     <td>1</td>   
     <td>2</td> 
     <td>3</td>
     <td>4</td>
     <td>5</td>
     <td>6</td>
     <td>7</td>  
     <td>8</td> 
  </tr>
  <tr>
     <td class="report-content-cell">
       <div class="main">fas</div>
     </td>
     <td>1</td>   
     <td>2</td> 
     <td>3</td>
     <td>4</td>
     <td>5</td>
     <td>6</td>
     <td>7</td>  
     <td>8</td> 
  </tr>
  <tr>
     <td class="report-content-cell">
       <div class="main">fas</div>
     </td>
     <td>1</td>   
     <td>2</td> 
     <td>3</td>
     <td>4</td>
     <td>5</td>
     <td>6</td>
     <td>7</td>  
     <td>8</td> 
  </tr>
  <tr>
     <td class="report-content-cell">
       <div class="main">fas</div>
     </td>
     <td>1</td>   
     <td>2</td> 
     <td>3</td>
     <td>4</td>
     <td>5</td>
     <td>6</td>
     <td>7</td>  
     <td>8</td> 
  </tr>
  <tr>
     <td class="report-content-cell">
       <div class="main">fas</div>
     </td>
     <td>1</td>   
     <td>2</td> 
     <td>3</td>
     <td>4</td>
     <td>5</td>
     <td>6</td>
     <td>7</td>  
     <td>8</td> 
  </tr>
  <tr>
     <td class="report-content-cell">
       <div class="main">fas</div>
     </td>
     <td>1</td>   
     <td>2</td> 
     <td>3</td>
     <td>4</td>
     <td>5</td>
     <td>6</td>
     <td>7</td>  
     <td>8</td> 
  </tr>
  <tr>
     <td class="report-content-cell">
       <div class="main">fas</div>
     </td>
     <td>1</td>   
     <td>2</td> 
     <td>3</td>
     <td>4</td>
     <td>5</td>
     <td>6</td>
     <td>7</td>  
     <td>8</td> 
  </tr>
  <tr>
     <td class="report-content-cell">
       <div class="main">fas</div>
     </td>
     <td>1</td>   
     <td>2</td> 
     <td>3</td>
     <td>4</td>
     <td>5</td>
     <td>6</td>
     <td>7</td>  
     <td>8</td> 
  </tr>
  <tr>
     <td class="report-content-cell">
       <div class="main">fas</div>
     </td>
     <td>1</td>   
     <td>2</td> 
     <td>3</td>
     <td>4</td>
     <td>5</td>
     <td>6</td>
     <td>7</td>  
     <td>8</td> 
  </tr>
  <tr>
     <td class="report-content-cell">
       <div class="main">fas</div>
     </td>
     <td>1</td>   
     <td>2</td> 
     <td>3</td>
     <td>4</td>
     <td>5</td>
     <td>6</td>
     <td>7</td>  
     <td>8</td> 
  </tr>
  <tr>
     <td class="report-content-cell">
       <div class="main">fas</div>
     </td>
     <td>1</td>   
     <td>2</td> 
     <td>3</td>
     <td>4</td>
     <td>5</td>
     <td>6</td>
     <td>7</td>  
     <td>8</td> 
  </tr>
  <tr>
     <td class="report-content-cell">
       <div class="main">fas</div>
     </td>
     <td>1</td>   
     <td>2</td> 
     <td>3</td>
     <td>4</td>
     <td>5</td>
     <td>6</td>
     <td>7</td>  
     <td>8</td> 
  </tr>
  <tr>
     <td class="report-content-cell">
       <div class="main">fas</div>
     </td>
     <td>1</td>   
     <td>2</td> 
     <td>3</td>
     <td>4</td>
     <td>5</td>
     <td>6</td>
     <td>7</td>  
     <td>8</td> 
  </tr>
  <tr>
     <td class="report-content-cell">
       <div class="main">fas</div>
     </td>
     <td>1</td>   
     <td>2</td> 
     <td>3</td>
     <td>4</td>
     <td>5</td>
     <td>6</td>
     <td>7</td>  
     <td>8</td> 
  </tr>
  <tr>
     <td class="report-content-cell">
       <div class="main">fas</div>
     </td>
     <td>1</td>   
     <td>2</td> 
     <td>3</td>
     <td>4</td>
     <td>5</td>
     <td>6</td>
     <td>7</td>  
     <td>8</td> 
  </tr>
  <tr>
     <td class="report-content-cell">
       <div class="main">fas</div>
     </td>
     <td>1</td>   
     <td>2</td> 
     <td>3</td>
     <td>4</td>
     <td>5</td>
     <td>6</td>
     <td>7</td>  
     <td>8</td> 
  </tr>
  <tr>
     <td class="report-content-cell">
       <div class="main">fas</div>
     </td>
     <td>1</td>   
     <td>2</td> 
     <td>3</td>
     <td>4</td>
     <td>5</td>
     <td>6</td>
     <td>7</td>  
     <td>8</td> 
  </tr>
  <tr>
     <td class="report-content-cell">
       <div class="main">fas</div>
     </td>
     <td>1</td>   
     <td>2</td> 
     <td>3</td>
     <td>4</td>
     <td>5</td>
     <td>6</td>
     <td>7</td>  
     <td>8</td> 
  </tr>
  </tbody>
  </table>
  </body>
```

> Javascript

```
    <script ="text/javascript">

    function printDiv() {
     var divToPrint = document.getElementById('table');
     var htmlToPrint = '' +
    '<style type="text/css">' +
        'table td {' +
    'border:1px solid #dddddd;' +
    'padding:8px;' +
    '}' +

    'table  {' +
    'border-collapse: collapse;' +
    'width: 100%;' +
    '}' +
    '</style>';
    htmlToPrint += divToPrint.outerHTML;
    newWin = window.open("");
    newWin.document.write(htmlToPrint);
    newWin.print();
    newWin.close();
   }
   </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, what you're trying to do isn't really part of the spec for `thead` and `tfoot` elements. But there are a few "hacks" that you can use to emulate the desired effect. Here is one that comes to mind:

For the table footer, you can set its display to `table-row-group`, remove it from the table, then append it to the table.

```
// Make footer visible on last page only
let tbl = document.getElementById('table');
let footer = tbl.getElementsByTagName('tfoot')[0];
footer.style.display = 'table-row-group';
tbl.removeChild(footer);
tbl.appendChild(footer);
```

For the table header, or really just the **title**, I would just clone the "title" node, apply the desired styling, prepend it to the table, and remove the original node.

```
// Make header visible on first page only
let title = document.querySelector('.titles');
let newTitle = title.cloneNode(true);
newTitle.style.textAlign = "center";
newTitle.style.fontWeight = "bold";
tbl.prepend(newTitle);
title.remove();
```

These blocks can be added to the top of your print function, as shown in the updated Fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/5azfn7wu/